# MUI 5 TextField to allow numbers with two decimal points

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following requirements

1. Input field should allow only 0 to 9 and decimal point
2. Should not start or end with the decimal point (Decimal point should be in the middle)
3. After the decimal point should have only two digits

I have generated a regex for this using chatGpt

```
'^(?!^\\.||.*\\.$)\\d+(\\.\\d{0,2})?$'
```

According to MUI official docs, this is how you add a pattern

```
<TextField inputProps={{ inputMode: 'numeric', pattern: '[0-9]*' }} />
```

I tried both the official example and my own one like this

```
<TextField inputProps={{ inputMode: "numeric", pattern: "[0-9]*" }} />
      <TextField
        inputProps={{
          inputMode: "numeric",
          pattern: "^(?!^\\.||.*\\.$)\\d+(\\.\\d{0,2})?$"
        }}
      />
```

Seems the pattern is not picking up

[This is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-shockley-ndzmt5)

Comment: I am able to achieve mentioned requirements this way: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-stitch-4nk3rh?file=/Demo.tsx (Code written by chatGPT but working as expected)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how Implement to allow

- only 0 to 9
- should not start or end with decimal point
- After decimal point should have only two digits

this may help please check the link below
[Code Sample for your problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-hodgkin-95w577?file=/Demo.tsx)

there is a function which check reg expression if value is valid.

```
// State variable to store change value
        const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
    // is valid function to check value is valid 
      const isValidInput = (value) => {
        const regex = /^(?!.*\..*\.)[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/;
        return regex.test(value);
      };
    // change function to set value to text field on change
      const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const inputValue = event.target.value;
    
        if (isValidInput(inputValue)) {
          setInputValue(inputValue);
        }
      };
```

and this is the text field

```
 <Box>
      {/* <TextField inputProps={{ inputMode: "numeric", pattern: "[0-9]*" }} /> */}
      <TextField
        label="Number"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        value={inputValue}
      />
    </Box>
```